# How to keep docker data safe and in accessible place?

Tags: docker

After volume mapping which of the ways below will keep the data in safe and accessible place?

1. Migrate the container
2. Break the container
3. Re-create the container
4. Backup the container

Comment: are you taking an exam?

Comment: Not an exam but someone asked me personally with these options since I've just started learning docker.

Comment: Not a well formed question.

Answer (score 0):

- re-create the container
- migrate the container
- backup the container